# Email to include ranges from different sheets

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I wanted to use VBA to send an outlook email with ranges from three different sheets in the workbook, how can I combine the three ranges(rng1 then leave a blank row, then rng2 and leave a blank row, then rng3) in order to show them in the same email? I tried the below code but there is a

> type mismatch error

```
Set rngComb = rng1 & rng2 & rng3
```

I'm not sure how to modify it.

```
Sub combEmail()
Dim OutApp As Object, OutMail As Object
Dim rngComb As Range, rng1 As Range, rng2 As Range, rng3 As Range

Set rng1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C12:F14")
Set rng2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("C16:F18")
Set rng3 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet3").Range("H12:K14")
Set rngComb = rng1 & rng2 & rng3

Set OutApp = CreateObejct("Outlook.Application")
Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

    With OutMail
        .To = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value
        .Subject = "CombinedNotice"
        .HTMLBody = RangetoHTML(rngComb)
        .display
    End With
    Set OutMail = Nothing
        
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Using Ron de Bruin's RangetoHTML](https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s1/outlook/bmail2.htm)

You would need to run `RangetoHTML` on each one individually. That will give you an HTML `String` for each one.

They can then be concatenated.

```
Dim sHTML As String
sHTML = RangetoHTML(rng1) & "<br>" & RangetoHTML(rng2) & "<br>" & RangetoHTML(rng3)
```

and then

```
.HTMLBody = sHTML
```

---

Or just:

```
.HTMLBody = RangetoHTML(rng1) & "<br>" & RangetoHTML(rng2) & "<br>" & RangetoHTML(rng3)
```

To add more space between each one, add more `<br>` tags. - `"<br><br><br><br>"`

---

**From the RangetoHTML code page:**

Important: Be aware that if you have set Excel to R1C1 reference style the code will not work.
You can add this line at the start of your macro to be sure it is set to xlA1 style

```
Application.ReferenceStyle = xlA1
```

And this one to set it back if you need

```
Application.ReferenceStyle = xlR1C1
```

Comment: Thanks @braX! I tried your method, but I don't uderstand why it gives me a compile error: ByRef argument type mismatch at `(rng1)` in line
`.HTMLBody = RangetoHTML(rng1) & "<br>" & RangetoHTML(rng2) & "<br>" & RangetoHTML(rng3)`

Comment: hi @braX, thanks for your quick reply! I did, please see `Set OutApp = CreateObejct("Outlook.Application")
Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)`. I just set to xlA1 style and tried, but I still get the same compile error at `(rng1）`

Comment: Thanks so much @braX ! I finally found out what was wrong. In my code( on my company's pc, I can't use company pc to login stackoverflow), when I declared rng1, rng2 and rng3, I wrote `Dim rng1, rng2, rng3 as Range`. It works perfectly now! thanks a lot!!

Comment: That would do it, as then only `rng3` is a `Range`, the other 2 are `Variant` type.